# How we can get url from local storage in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, url, server, fragment

How we can get url from local storage? I need to send the image that I've picked from local storage to server. My friend told me to get url from the image. How can i do that? I work on fragment rather than activity. This is my fragment code: https://codeshare.io/3AMWY6 and this is my viewmodel code: https://codeshare.io/Lw0xnl I can get image from gallery but can't send it to my server. And my friend says that what i need to do is to get the url from the image. But i don't know the way to do it because i new in kotlin. Thank you for answering.

Comment: URLs don't come from images.  Your friend is wrong.

Comment: The image type that required in the server is string ($binary). How can i send the image to the server? I've search in the google and youtub but it seems i can't find tutorial. Do you have any reference? Thank you.

Comment: There's no possible way we could answer that question without you telling us more about the server.